# jQuery Mobile popup opens only after an Alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I´m new to JQM and Ajax pages. I got 2 inputs, both with a DateBox, in which users select "from" and "until" dates. I´m trying to do a validation in which if the "until" date is before de "from" Date, a jQuery mobile popup opens. The problem is that it will only open if I remove the DateBox by code after setting the date and I put an alert before calling the popup. Here´s the code:

```
$('form.criterio').on('datebox', function (e, passed) {  
        
        if ( passed.method === 'set' ) {  
                if ($('input.buscaFecha[name="valor"]').val() != "" && $('input.buscaFecha[name="valor2"]').val() != ""){
                    $('.ui-datebox-container').remove();
                    var fechaValor = ($('input.buscaFecha[name="valor"]').val()).split('/');
                    var fechaDesde = new Date(fechaValor[2], fechaValor[1]-1, fechaValor[0]);
                    var fechaValor2 = ($('input.buscaFecha[name="valor2"]').val()).split('/');
                    var fechaHasta = new Date(fechaValor2[2], fechaValor2[1]-1, fechaValor2[0]);
                    if( fechaDesde > fechaHasta) {
                        alert();
                        $('#errorFecha').popup('open');
                    }
                };
        };
    });
```

Any ideas? I don't know what else to try.